# Alternative idiom or phrasal verb for eating an elephant one bite at a time

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

> Eat an elephant one bite at a time.

I am looking for an alternative to this idiom that expresses the same idea.

The idea expressed: If a big task is given, tackle it piece by piece

Comment: 'a journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step'  (although this is from the Tao te Ching) or more generally "one step at a time",

Comment: You could also say you're "chipping away at" the task

Answer (score 4):

There are probably lots of similar sayings, but the common one that springs to mind is:

> slow and steady wins the race

Although it doesn't specifically mention breaking a task into pieces, this commonly used proverb is about being *methodical* with respect to both speed and accuracy.

A longer version of the proverb is said less often:

> Slow and steady wins the race, not the person who wants to climb the whole stairs in one stride.